# Correctly move rigidbody at constant speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

this is currently my code. The object moves at the desired speed but using [rb.velocity = movement * speed] if it jump it remains glued to the ground. I can't understand how I can fix things

```
private Vector3 movement;
private float speed = 3;
public bool isGrounded;

void Start()

rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

void Update()
{
float Horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float Vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
movement = transform.right * Horizontal + transform.forward * Vertical;
float origMagnitude = movement.magnitude;
movement.y = 0.0f;
movement = movement.normalized * origMagnitude;

if(isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
rb.AddForce((Vector3.up + movement) * JumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit, rayDistance, layer)) isGrounded = true;
else isGrounded = false;
}

private void FixedUpdate ()
{      
     rb.velocity = movement * speed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "AddForce" adds a force to the rigidbody. That means that the rigidbody will keep on moving in this direction (the force vector) until something stops it (friction or other objects). If you keep adding forces to the rigidbody, the total force will increase and, as a result, the speed will keep growing.

There is a simple way to move a rigidbody, just use its position property:

For example:

```
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); \\ From your program
rb.position = rb.position + movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime; \\ Instead of MovePosition
```

As far as I knew (from unity scripting API) MoveRotation works on a non kinematic rigidbody.
If it doen't work, you can do the same as the movement (use the rotation property).

For more information, you can see: [Unity Scripting API - Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html)

Comment: thanks but In this way the object moves but the speed of the rigidbody is not calculated, it is as if it were still and if it collides with something it has no impact. I also tried "rb.velocity = movement * speed;" it works but in this way I have problems in the jumps

Comment: You can set "Addforce" one time to set the force and to stop it  you can use - rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;    rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
Does this helps?

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly can you put it in a script please?

Comment: for example:

if (condition){
    rb.addForce (movement * speed);
    rest condition;
}
if (reached destination){
    rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero; 
    rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
}

Comment: I solved so, even if it is very expensive as a method but else at the moment i not have others soluction. Do you have any suggestion or know how to rotate in the direction of the camera?

 private void FixedUpdate ()
          
if (movement.sqrMagnitude > 0.0f && isGrounded)
if(rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude < speed)
rb.AddForce(movement * speed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

Answer (score 0):

just try to ask for the speed:
like

```cs
void FixedUpdate()
{ 
    if(rb.velocity.magnitude < "set here your speed variable" )
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;
}
```

Comment: By changing `velocity` you are discarding all the Unity engine physics computations. E.g. during a fall such an object will not have any acceleration.

Comment: This worked for my use case.  It may have the issue above, but at least it's "correct" in the best case.  Better than most answers online.